# MapFrom not always mapping properly

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Here's a piece of simple code:

```
 var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactDtoGrid>().
                    ForMember("executive_account", x => x.MapFrom(y => y.executive_account.Id)).
                    ForMember("executive_account_Name", x => x.MapFrom(y => y.executive_account.Name));

foreach (Contact c in allContacts)
{
     string accountNumber = accounts.Where(x=>x.Key==c.executive_account.Id).SingleOrDefault().Value;

     string protocolDescription = (protocolDefinitions.Where(x => x.ProtocolOptionSetValue == c.executive_protocol).Any()) ? protocolDefinitions.Where(x => x.ProtocolOptionSetValue == c.executive_protocol).SingleOrDefault().PortalDescription : string.Empty;


    if (protocolDescription != string.Empty)
      Console.Write(protocolDescription); //I do get an output so it's not always empty

    map.ForMember("executive_account_Number", x => x.MapFrom(y => accountNumber));
    map.ForMember("executive_protocol_desc", x => x.MapFrom(y => protocolDescription));

    var contactDto = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactDtoGrid>(c);

}
```

So all properties map properly, except for `executive_protocol_desc` which is always an empty string. Like I mentionned in the comment above, this is the case regardless whether `protocolDescription` is an empty string or not.

Am I doing something obviously wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're calling `CreateMap` for each iteration of a loop for the same pair of types?

Comment: @KirkWoll Optimzed the code, but I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the method, you're not really doing a `MapFrom`, but setting a value. Since automapper is using nested closures, it's just easier to use a direct assignment:

```
...
var contactDto = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactDtoGrid>(c);
contactDto.executive_protocol_desc = protocolDescription;
```

If you need to keep it in the mapper, you should be able to just put the protocol magic as the expression. This would allow you to pull the protocol description out of the foreach loop. Note: I also simplified the linq expression.

```
map.ForMember("executive_protocol_desc", opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
    protocolDefinitions.Any(pdef => pdef.ProtocolOptionSetValue == src.executive_protocol)) 
    ? protocolDefinitions.SingleOrDefault(pdef => pdef.ProtocolOptionSetValue == src.executive_protocol).PortalDescription
    : string.Empty)
```

Comment: It's not only easier, it is safer. It is bad practice to change mappings after initializing them (as with any static state). The direction of the mapping after the loop now depends on whether or not `allContacts` has items. And if it has, the mapping has captured the last values of the two variables for the rest of the application's lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

I took those lines out of the loop:

```
map.ForMember("executive_account_Number", x => x.MapFrom(y => accountNumber));
map.ForMember("executive_protocol_desc", x => x.MapFrom(y => protocolDescription));
```

And before the loop kicks in, I changed it to this:

```
map.ForMember(dest => dest.executive_protocol_desc, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => protocolDefinitions.Where(y => y.ProtocolOptionSetValue == x.executive_protocol.Value).SingleOrDefault().PortalDescription));
map.ForMember(dest => dest.executive_account_Number, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => accounts.Where(y => y.Key == x.executive_account.Id).SingleOrDefault().Value));
```

Now this maps properly.